# Encountered error "Cannot convert type System.Nullable`1[System.Int64][] to an R vector"

Tags: r, azure-data-lake, u-sql, data-lake

I'm trying to run a job on Data Lake Store, but I get an error.

I inserted into the `u-sql` script an `R` script.

In my R script I use the dataset to calculate the percentiles of my variable and as output I create a dataframe that contains the result of the calculation.

this is a part of my script:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [ExtR]; 
DECLARE @data string = @"/output/model/...";
DECLARE @Model_traffic_percentile_outputfile string = "/output/model/...";
DECLARE @myRScript = @"
prob <- c(0.9999995,0.9999996,0.9999997,0.9999998,0.9999999,1)
values <- quantile(inputFromUSQL$total_bytes, probs = prob, type = 6)
outputToUSQL <- data.frame(values, prob)";

@input = 
EXTRACT [Period] string,
        [H_IMSI_BK] long,
        [H_BTSCarrierExternalCode_BK] long,
        [sum_session_duration] long,
        [sum_session_bytes_in] long,
        [sum_session_bytes_out] long,
        [sum_session_count] long
FROM @data
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);

@imsi_traffic_data =
SELECT [H_IMSI_BK],
       SUM(([sum_session_bytes_in] + [sum_session_bytes_out]) * [row_count]) AS [total_bytes]
FROM @input
GROUP BY [H_IMSI_BK];

@ExtendedData =
SELECT [total_bytes] AS Par,
   *
FROM @imsi_traffic_data;

@RScriptOutput = REDUCE @ExtendedData ON Par
  PRODUCE Par, values long, prob float
  READONLY Par
  USING new Extension.R.Reducer(
    command:@myRScript,
    rReturnType:"dataframe",
    stringsAsFactors:false);

OUTPUT @RScriptOutput TO @Model_traffic_percentile_outputfile
  USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader : true, quoting : false);
```

But I get this error:

Description

```
Vertex failure triggered quick job abort. Vertex failed: SV2_Aggregate[0] 
with error: Vertex user code error.
```

Details

```
Vertex SV2_Aggregate[0].v1 {669A5438-5EFD-437D-906C-F069CCD2C5B4} failed 

Error:
Vertex user code error

exitcode=CsExitCode_StillActive Errorsnippet=
```

INNERERROR

Description

```
Unhandled exception from user code: "Cannot convert type 
System.Nullable`1[System.Int64][] to an R vector"
The details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised.
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the R script can not handle 64-bit data types.

To create the input dataset I used the script that is generated by default by the command `Create EXTRACT script`, which in this case automatically assigns to all the fields of the dataset the data types `long`, which contains 64-bit values.

So I modified the extract script changing the data types in this way:

```
@InputData = 
    EXTRACT [Period] string,
            [H_IMSI_BK] string,
            [H_BTSCarrierExternalCode_BK] string,
            [sum_session_duration] int,
            [sum_session_bytes_in] double,
            [sum_session_bytes_out] double,
            [sum_session_count] int,
            [row_count] int
    FROM @data
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);
```

While to handle the nullable types I modified the script in this way:

```
@imsi_traffic_data =
SELECT [H_IMSI_BK],
       SUM(([sum_session_bytes_in] + [sum_session_bytes_out]) * [row_count]) ?? 0 AS [total_bytes]
FROM @InputData
GROUP BY [H_IMSI_BK];
```

With these changes the script works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the current R integration does not support nullable types. The SUM() operator returns a nullable type, so you get the type mismatch error.

You can circumvent this issue, by casting the result of the sum to a non-nullable type. E.g., try

```
@imsi_traffic_data =
SELECT [H_IMSI_BK],
       (double) SUM(([sum_session_bytes_in] + [sum_session_bytes_out]) * [row_count]) AS [total_bytes]
FROM @input
GROUP BY [H_IMSI_BK];
```

Note that we will address this in a future refresh of the R extension.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the solution you proposed is not correct, returns the same error!
I solved the error now, the problem is the type of data contained within the columns.
Now I post the correct solution below

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. Please note that you still need to handle the null value case eventually.